# System.StackOverflowException on vb.net when closing WinForm from System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I'm having trouble with a background worker and a form. 
I'm trying to call me.close on the worker event RunWorkerCompleted but it trows a StackOverflow Exception on the overrided "Dispose" Sub of the myform.Designer.vb file. 
It worked some time before I overloaded the "New" constructor because of need, and now I always get a StackOverflow Exception, but I don't know why. 
I've not changed the designer file, but if I use the previous code, it does not fail. 
Can I increase the stack size as a temporary solution?
Is this a result of a race condition?
I've also tried to increase the background process priority and lower the UI one, with no luck.

My form code is as follows:

```
Public Class frmProgreso

Private elImpresionCancelada As Boolean
Private WithEvents miWorker As System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker
Private miListaReports As Report.EnumNombreReport()
Private miListaReportsStr As String(,)
Private miInforme_ruta As String
Private miEmpresa As String
Private miAño As Integer
Private miMes As Integer
Private oReport As Report
Private lasCategorias As String()
Private got_closing_order As Boolean = False

Public Sub New(ByVal ListaReports As Report.EnumNombreReport(), ByVal Empresa As String, ByVal Año As Integer, ByVal Mes As Integer, ByVal OpcionMenu As String, ByVal Categorias As String())

    ' Llamada necesaria para el diseñador.
    InitializeComponent()

    ' Agregue cualquier inicialización después de la llamada a InitializeComponent().
    miEmpresa = Empresa
    miAño = Año
    miMes = Mes
    lasCategorias = Categorias
    miListaReports = ListaReports
    ReiniciarInformes(0)
    ReiniciarCeldas(0)
    lblOpcionMenu.Text = OpcionMenu

End Sub
Public Sub New(ByVal informes As String(,), ByVal Empresa As String, ByVal Año As Integer, ByVal Mes As Integer, ByVal OpcionMenu As String, ByVal Categorias As String())

    ' Esta llamada es exigida por el diseñador.
    InitializeComponent()

    ' Agregue cualquier inicialización después de la llamada a InitializeComponent().
    miEmpresa = Empresa
    miAño = Año
    miMes = Mes
    lasCategorias = Categorias
    miListaReportsStr = informes
    ReiniciarInformes(0)
    ReiniciarCeldas(0)
    lblOpcionMenu.Text = OpcionMenu
End Sub
Public Sub New(ByVal ruta_completa_informe As String, ByVal Empresa As String, ByVal Año As Integer, ByVal Mes As Integer, ByVal OpcionMenu As String, ByVal Categorias As String())

    ' Esta llamada es exigida por el diseñador.
    InitializeComponent()

    ' Agregue cualquier inicialización después de la llamada a InitializeComponent().
    miEmpresa = Empresa
    miAño = Año
    miMes = Mes
    lasCategorias = Categorias
    miInforme_ruta = ruta_completa_informe
    ReiniciarInformes(0)
    ReiniciarCeldas(0)
    lblOpcionMenu.Text = OpcionMenu
End Sub

Public ReadOnly Property ProcesoCancelado() As Boolean
    Get
        Return elImpresionCancelada
    End Get
End Property

Public Sub ImprimirDesdeCatalogo(Optional ByVal informes As String(,) = Nothing)
    If Not IsNothing(informes) Then
        miListaReportsStr = informes
    End If
    Me.Show()
    LanzarImpresion()
End Sub

Public Sub ReiniciarCeldas(ByVal NumeroCeldas As Integer)
    pbCeldas.Minimum = 0
    pbCeldas.Maximum = NumeroCeldas
    pbCeldas.Value = pbCeldas.Minimum
    pbCeldas.Step = 1
    lblCeldas.Text = String.Empty
End Sub

Public Sub ReiniciarInformes(ByVal NumeroInformes As Integer)
    pbInformes.Minimum = 0
    pbInformes.Maximum = NumeroInformes * 3 'Para cada informe, se realizan tres pasos: carga de plantilla en array, procesamiento de celdas y carga de array en plantilla
    pbInformes.Step = 1
    pbInformes.Value = pbInformes.Minimum
    lblInforme.Text = String.Empty
End Sub

'Private Sub frmProgreso_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
'    If miWorker.IsBusy() Then
'        got_closing_order = True
'        miWorker.CancelAsync()
'        e.Cancel = True
'        Me.Enabled = False
'        Return
'    End If
'    MyBase.OnFormClosing(e)
'End Sub

Private Sub frmProgreso_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
    CentrarObjeto(gbPrincipal)
End Sub

Private Sub miWorker_DoWork(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles miWorker.DoWork
    System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().PriorityClass = System.Diagnostics.ProcessPriorityClass.RealTime
    If Not IsNothing(miListaReportsStr) Then
        'Proceso nuevo.
        miWorker.ReportProgress((UBound(miListaReportsStr, 1)) * 3, "INICIAR INFORMES") 'Para cada informe, se realizan tres pasos: carga de plantilla en array, procesamiento de celdas y carga de array en plantilla
        For i As Integer = 0 To UBound(miListaReportsStr, 1) - 1
            If miWorker.CancellationPending Then
                Exit For
            End If
            'miWorker.ReportProgress(1, miListaReports.ElementAt(i).ToString)
            oReport = New Report(miListaReportsStr(0, i), miEmpresa, miAño, miMes, miWorker, cRutaBase_InformesXLSGenerados, lasCategorias, miListaReportsStr(1, i))
            oReport.Imprimir(txtCeldaValidacion.Text.Trim)
        Next
    ElseIf miInforme_ruta <> "" Then
        'proceso nuevo fichero individual 
        miWorker.ReportProgress(3, "INICIAR INFORMES") 'Para cada informe, se realizan tres pasos: carga de plantilla en array, procesamiento de celdas y carga de array en plantilla
        'miWorker.ReportProgress(1, miListaReports.ElementAt(i).ToString)
        oReport = New Report(miInforme_ruta, miEmpresa, miAño, miMes, miWorker, cRutaBase_InformesXLSGenerados, lasCategorias)
        oReport.Imprimir(txtCeldaValidacion.Text.Trim)

    Else
        'Proceso Antiguo
        miWorker.ReportProgress(miListaReports.Length * 3, "INICIAR INFORMES") 'Para cada informe, se realizan tres pasos: carga de plantilla en array, procesamiento de celdas y carga de array en plantilla
        For i As Integer = 0 To miListaReports.Length - 1
            If miWorker.CancellationPending Then
                Exit For
            End If
            'miWorker.ReportProgress(1, miListaReports.ElementAt(i).ToString)
            oReport = New Report(miListaReports.ElementAt(i), miEmpresa, miAño, miMes, miWorker, cRutaBase_InformesXLSGenerados, lasCategorias)
            oReport.Imprimir(txtCeldaValidacion.Text.Trim)
        Next
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub miWorker_ProgressChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles miWorker.ProgressChanged
    If e.UserState = "INICIAR CELDAS" Then
        pbCeldas.Minimum = 0
        pbCeldas.Maximum = e.ProgressPercentage
        pbCeldas.Value = pbCeldas.Minimum
        pbCeldas.Step = 1
        lblCeldas.Text = String.Empty

    ElseIf e.UserState = "INCREMENTAR CELDAS" Then
        pbCeldas.Value = pbCeldas.Value + 1
        lblCeldas.Text = "Calculando celda " & pbCeldas.Value & "/" & pbCeldas.Maximum
        'If pbCeldas.Value = 9811 Then
        '    MessageBox.Show("1")
        'End If

    ElseIf e.UserState = "LEER CELDAS PLANTILLA" Then
        pbCeldas.Value = pbCeldas.Value + 1
        lblCeldas.Text = "Leyendo plantilla celda " & pbCeldas.Value & "/" & pbCeldas.Maximum

    ElseIf e.UserState = "VOLCAR CELDAS PLANTILLA" Then
        pbCeldas.Value = pbCeldas.Value + 1
        lblCeldas.Text = "Escribiendo en plantilla celda " & pbCeldas.Value & "/" & pbCeldas.Maximum

    ElseIf e.UserState = "INICIAR INFORMES" Then
        pbInformes.Minimum = 0
        pbInformes.Maximum = e.ProgressPercentage
        pbInformes.Value = pbInformes.Minimum
        pbInformes.Step = 1
        lblInforme.Text = String.Empty

    Else
        lblInforme.Text = "Imprimiendo...  < " & e.UserState & " >    (Fase " & (pbInformes.Value Mod 3) + 1 & "/3)" '
        pbInformes.Value = pbInformes.Value + e.ProgressPercentage
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub frmImportarInformesExcel_Paint(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) Handles Me.Paint
    CentrarObjeto(gbPrincipal)
End Sub

Private Sub butCancelarImpresion_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles butCancelarImpresion.Click
    If MessageBox.Show("¿Estás seguro de que deseas cancelar la impresión?", "Cancelar impresión", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button2) = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes Then
        elImpresionCancelada = True
        If oReport IsNot Nothing Then
            oReport.CancelarImpresion = True
        End If
        If miWorker IsNot Nothing Then
            miWorker.CancelAsync()
        End If
        'Me.Close()
        Me.Hide()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub LanzarImpresion()
    System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().PriorityClass = System.Diagnostics.Processpriorityclass.BelowNormal
    butComenzar.Enabled = False
    txtCeldaValidacion.Enabled = False
    lblInforme.Visible = True
    lblCeldas.Visible = True
    pbCeldas.Visible = True
    pbInformes.Visible = True
    lblOpcionMenu.Visible = False
    miWorker = New System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker()
    miWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = True
    miWorker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = True
    miWorker.RunWorkerAsync()
End Sub

Private Sub butComenzar_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles butComenzar.Click
    LanzarImpresion()
End Sub

Private Sub miWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles miWorker.RunWorkerCompleted
    ' a veces no se puede cerrar al usar el debugger... parece un error por utilizar hilos. ç
    miWorker.CancelAsync()
    miWorker.Dispose()
    miWorker = Nothing
    System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().PriorityClass = System.Diagnostics.ProcessPriorityClass.Normal
    Me.Dispose(False)
End Sub

Private Sub txtCeldaValidacion_LostFocus(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtCeldaValidacion.LostFocus
    txtCeldaValidacion.Text = Replace(Replace(Replace(txtCeldaValidacion.Text, " ", ""), ":", ""), "$", "")
End Sub

End Class
```

**Edit 1:**
I've been trying to watch the call stack and, yes, there is a stack overflow because the dispose method on the frmprogreso.designer.vb is being called lots of times. 
[Effective stack overflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GmZkr.jpg)
But from the user code side it's only called once as i  can see... 
[Only one call from user code side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d7xBx.jpg)

Comment: Set a breakpoint on the Dispose() method.  When it hits the second time you ought to get interested in the content of the Call Stack debugger window.  Post that content if you can't figure it out.

Comment: You modified the auto-generated code for some reason.  `Me.Dispose` is the fatal mistake, that used to be `MyBase.Dispose`.  Hard to guess how this happened, watch out for Edit > Replace perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

My fault was on myform.Designer.vb 
For some reason (maybe my own fault) the dispose method was as follows:

```
Protected Overrides Sub Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean)
    Try
        If disposing AndAlso components IsNot Nothing Then
            components.Dispose()
        End If
    Finally
        Me.Dispose(disposing)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Many Thanks to Hans Passant for pointing that the "Me.Dispose(disposing)" is the big fault, it's calling to itself. It should definetly be MyBase.Dispose(disposing)